# Extract proper nouns from PDF

Tags: r, text-mining

I have different pdf files in which I need to find location (so proper nouns). I already have used `pdftools` and `tdm` but the matrix I end up with is either too long (the locations don't occur that much in each texts)  or unreadable (it stemmed some location names). I tried with and without `stemming` and `tolover` activated.
I still tried to export the matrix with `write.csv` to search manually but it didn't work.
it's unable to convert automatically class `‘c("TermDocumentMatrix", "simple_triplet_matrix")’`.
I can't share the data because it is an ungoing research but I have 3OO pdf articles ("title.pdf").

```
library(tm)
library(pdftools)
files <- list.files(pattern = "pdf$")
opinions <- lapply(files, pdf_text)
lapply(opinions, length)
opinions
corp <- Corpus(URISource(files), readerControl = list(reader = readPDF))
opinions.tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(corp,
                               control =
                                 list(stopwords = TRUE,
                                      tolower = FALSE,
                                      stemming = TRUE,
                                      removeNumbers = TRUE,
                                      bounds = list(global = c(3, Inf))))
write.csv(opinions.tdm)
```

I'm looking for a way to extract only proper nouns from pdf and then extract the resulting matrix into a csv.
Note that the locations I'm looking for are unusual so I don't think a DB would work.

First time using stackoverflow, sorry if something is unclear.

Comment: Can you share an example of what the data looks like/what code you're using with pdftools?

Comment: @KJ unfortunately I'll have to do with proper nouns cause some of the locations I'm looking for are geological some geographical, some in english, chinese or french. It would be to hard to make a list.